# Падежные окончания числительных в сочетании с "на глубине...", "на высоте...", "на расстоянии..." и т. п

Tags: согласование, падежи, числительные, окончания

Не кажутся ли вам странными сочетания в родительном падеже а-ля "на глубине двух километров", "на высоте двухсот метров"? Ведь получается логика: на глубине / на высоте ЧЕГО... То есть глубина принадлежит километрам (= глубина километров), высота принадлежит метрам (= высота метров)... Разве не правильнее будет оставить в именительном: "на глубине два километра", "на высоте двести метров"?.. Судя по всему, норма допускает оба варианта (см. [Грамоту.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=291890)), а ещё допускает наличие предлога "в": "на глубине в два километра" (см. тоже [Грамоту.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=203768)).

Какое существует правило на этот счёт и почему, как вы думаете, вариант с родительным падежом вроде как встречается чаще?

Comment: И так будет правильно: глубина в четыре и пять аршин.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта тема задает способ выражения **количественных отношений** между предметом, его величиной (размером, весом и др.) и числовым определителем этой величины

1. В грамматике-80 в § 1856 говорится о вариативности записи подобных отношений, когда разрешаются, к примеру,  следующие формы: **канава шириной в два метра** (В.п.)– **канава в два метра** (В.п.) – **канава шириной два метра** (И.п.). Таким образом, допускается форма В.п. и И.п. для числового определителя.

http://rusgram.narod.ru/1830-1861.html

Мы можем сказать: *впадина глубиной в два километра* и *впадина глубиной два километра.* Грамматически более точным является В.п. (связь управление), но И.п. в качестве определителя тоже возможен. В приведенных примерах величина обозначена **формой Т.п.**

2. А если оценивать **только величину,** например: ***Здесь глубина – два километра.*** В этом предложении надо ставить тире, но по правилам допускается его пропуск.

Но можно ли сказать так: ***на глубине (какой?) два километра.*** Чувствуется разговорный стиль, так как связь не обозначена, но такая запись тоже допускается.

При наличии падежного управления можно использовать следующие формы:  **на глубине в два километра** (В.п) и **на глубине двух километров** (Р.п.)

3. Откуда берется беспредложный  Р.п.? Эта форма в качестве определения используется в русском языке часто: *воронка огромного размера, мебель красного дерева*.

Поэтому грамматически более точным является предложное или беспредложное управление, а отсутствие управления (И.п) следует отнести к разговорному стилю.